# Move coordinates of UIView to LLO with Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, cgaffinetransform

I would expect this code to move my `newLabel` from the upper left corner (ULO) to the lower left corner (LLO) but it doesn't! Apparently I need someone to hold my hand through the process of setting (0, 0) to LLO for a `UIView`. I've been through the documentation and read post after post on this forum but can't seem to make it happen. Disclaimer: I am trying to accomplish this in a playground in xCode 6 beta 2 so it possible it's a bug or not supported.

```
var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50))
newLabel.text = "This is a test"
newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
newLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.8)

var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100))
myView.layer.borderWidth = 2
myView.addSubview(newLabel)
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Add this line or just see answer  self.view.addSubview(myView);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To flip the UIView it has to be a subView of another view... My issue was I was trying to flip the mainView or baseView which apparently cant be done. This make since, since it needs a graphic space to be able to draw to. Below is the code achieving what I was looking for. Also of not I also had to "flip" my label as well to return it to it upright state (again this is logical).

```
var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50))
newLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
newLabel.text = "This is a test"
newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
newLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.8)

var subView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100))
subView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
subView.layer.borderWidth = 2
subView.addSubview(newLabel)
subView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)

var myView = UIView()
myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200))
//myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
myView.layer.borderWidth = 2
myView.addSubview(subView)
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.8, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
```

[image]

Thanks @Mohit for your input in helping me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't added Myview in main view try this code:--

```
     var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50))
    newLabel.text = "This is a test"
    newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
    newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    newLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.8)

    var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100))
    myView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    myView.addSubview(newLabel)
    myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
    self.view.addSubview(myView);
```

Comment: This is done in playground in xCode 6 using Swift... There is no class or function here that I would reference with `self` and no property/variable/constant that I would reference with `view`. This does not work and gives me the error: `Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:19:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
self.view.addSubview(myView)
^`

Comment: This did get me thinking though... maybe for the `CGAffineTransform` to work it needed to be a subview and not the main/base view and in fact it did.